# Using a cartisan product to created a list of comparisons with no duplicate questions

Tags: sql-server, view

I'm writing a query that will be used to generate a list for a test, where every item will be compared to ever other item, and then one uped or downed. For instance with a list of three items -

- Puppies
- Movies
- Walks in the Park
- Reading

the test will ask if you prefer

Puppies or movies,

Puppies or walks in the park

Puppies or Reading

Movies or walks in the park

Movies or reading

Walks in the Park or reading.

Using a create view query I ALMOST get this.

```
CREATE VIEW testquestionsvw AS  

select  t1.testItem AS firstItem,  

        t2.testItem AS secondItem   

from    testcontents t1 JOIN testcontents t2 on t1.testItem != t2.testItem;
```

But it has the issue of duplicate questions. It will ask -

Movies or Puppies

then

Puppies or Movies.

I know there's an elegant way of writing the query to not do this, to ask each question only once, but I haven't done much SQL lately and I'm pulling a blank. I could just deal with it in the test program itself rather then here, but that seems more awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a row number and perform a `JOIN`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/348ca/1/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TestItem)
    FROM TestContents
)
SELECT 
    FirstItem = t1.TestItem,
    SecondItem = t2.TestItem
FROM Cte t1
INNER JOIN Cte t2
    ON t2.RN > t1.RN
    AND t2.TestItem != t1.TestItem
```

Comment: You can't use ORDER BY in view, but I can just use it as a caned query which is basically just as good. I knew there was an easy solution, sorry for the softball question.

Comment: You're right. I forgot it's supposed to be in a VIEW. Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition currently checks that both items are different, so you get every combination twice (`x,y` and `y,x`). The easiest way to solve this is just to make an arbitrary decision to always put the first (lexicographically) item on the left:

```
CREATE VIEW testquestionsvw AS  
SELECT  t1.testItem AS firstItem,  
        t2.testItem AS secondItem   
FROM    testcontents t1 
JOIN    testcontents t2 ON t1.testItem < t2.testItem;
```

(Of course you could make the opposite arbitrary decision and use `>` instead of `<`).